# What does "timeless advice" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Somebody said about a comment posted by anyone else that is a *timeless advice*.

What does this exactly mean? Does it mean the comment is very long?

---

I did search on the internet about the meaning of this and didn't find an explanation of this specific group of words.

Comment: What did googling tell you? What does your dictionary say about the words *timeless* and *advice*? Given those two definitions, what do you infer the phrase means? Help us help you. Show us what effort you put into answering this question for yourself before asking a bunch of strangers on the internet to donate their time to you.

Comment: [timeless](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/timeless) *lasting, classic, enduring, ageless, permanent, perpetual, perennial, abiding, unfailing, unchanging, never-changing, changeless, unvarying, unfading, invariable, unending, without end, ceaseless, never dying, undying, deathless, immortal, eternal, everlasting, immutable, indestructible, imperishable*. In the context of ***advice***, the implication is it always was and always will be *good* advice.

Comment: OK, I updated my question. I did search this on the internet.

Comment: @IonicăBizău You need to also add what you found in the dictionary, for both words, and then tell us what you inferred the phrase means based on that research. It's very easy for anyone to say "I have a question ... ok you guys want research but I googled and didn't find anything, please tell me the answer". We want people who are motivated to help themselves first.

Comment: @JasperLoy It's not that he has to figure it out, it's that he has to demonstrate he *tried before asking*, and tell us what conclusions he came to, even if they miss the mark, which is fine. And yes, recognizing that using even focused resources like a dictionary can be challenging for a student of a new language is why we set up ELL; I'm just trying to get OP to whip the Q into sufficient shape that we can migrate it there in good conscience, and so that he's equipped to ask further good questions there, which will be well-received and hopefully lead to a fruitful career on the site for him.

Comment: JasperLoy, *"Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."* Similarly, let's help new users do their own research first. So it's better to avoid answering general-reference questions. This is a timeless advice, too. :)

Comment: Sorry if it was a bad question—I know the philosophy of SE when asking questions (I'm more active on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420197/ionică-bizău)). In this case, I kept searching about 20 minutes to find the answer, and I just couldn't get it.  Then I finally asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Timeless](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/timeless)* here means not affected by the passing of time. This means the advice was useful in the past, still is useful today, and will continue to be useful in the future.